# How do I trouble shoot input fields that won't focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure what happened but when I touch or click any of my input fields they don't become focused. I can still log the touch or click event on these inputs though.

Where can I start to trouble shoot this issue? The code base is large so it's hard for me provide exact context or exact code that might be causing the issue.

Thanks for any direction.

:thanks for the suggestions so far.

EDIT: Still haven't figured it out but I am still able to tab to the inputs and focus on them. If that helps anyone try to help with the vague context I'm providing.

Thanks again.

Comment: `when I touch or click any of my input fields they don't become focused`. And you expect an answer from this problem description? I wouldn't. If the code is so large maybe it's time for you to start dissecting it and removing parts of it until you are able to reproduce the problem into a small snippet that you could post here (or even better on http://jsfiddle.net) to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov -- I disagree. If he wanted the solution to the problem, then he'd certainly be asking far too much. But he simply asked about where to start troubleshooting the issue. That's definitely answerable.

Comment: You can start by posting a well formulated question that includes some relevant code.  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @maxedison, of course, that's why I answered him to start dissecting his code until he is able to isolate the problem. Until then it's pretty meaningless to ask such questions on StackOverflow. Well, actually I didn't post it as answer, since I answer only questions that have sense and this one doesn't to me. That's why I commented and voted to close.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov -- that wasn't in your initial comment. Which is what I was responding to.

Comment: Platform? Browser? Version? - Firefox has KNOWN issues with the insertion point/caret disappearing

Comment: @mplungjan Mostly testing with Chrome and Mobile Safari at this point.

Comment: I would advise that you expand your question because you're not providing enough information for anyone to realistically help you. This usually leads to a protracted and frustrating round of requests in the comments for more information by other users who **really do want to help you**. For example, include in the question: code snippets/samples, the API you're using, stack traces, screen shots etc. When you've done this, flag to have your question re-opened. Please also take the time to [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Thanks.

Comment: @Kev, actually maybe this is an outlier case or something but one of the answers has helped very much. I have it 90% figured out now. I don't think people should be so quick to come down on these types of questions. I was stuck people gave me some paths to look down and a lot of the time that's all you need.

Comment: Solved this due to answers provided with the information give. Thanks for the helpful information. It answered my real question and helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad that you solved it. I don't think this question should have been closed. Learning good debugging techniques is critical to programming, and that often means you first have to learn how to debug broader, more ambiguous issues. You were asking how to start debugging, and got criticized for not having done the precise kind of debugging you were asking for assistance on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look through the code for anything that binds click or focus events. Something within those event handlers must be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to troubleshoot events. Create a bookmark with this as the url:

```
javascript:(function(){if(typeof VisualEvent!='undefined'){if(document.getElementById('Event_display')){VisualEvent.fnClose();}else{VisualEvent.fnInit();}}else{var n=document.createElement('script');n.setAttribute('language','JavaScript');n.setAttribute('src','http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/design/event/media/js/event-loader.js');document.body.appendChild(n);}})();;
```

Next, go to the page that has issues and click the bookmark. This will create an overlay showing you all events that are bound on that page and their handlers, and allow you to trigger them. This may help shed some light on what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Use firebug or Chrome debugger and try inspecting the element.  That should tell you if you have something on top of it that are not noticing.

Next check any javascript that binds to the element and either `return false` or `.preventDefault()`

Last but not least, use "break on next" in either of the aforementioned debuggers and step through the click event.

Comment: I don't think there's anything overlaying the fields because the OP says "I can still log the touch or click event on these inputs though."